# Как сделать перевернутую цифру более коротким кодом или циклом?

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

Я сделал перевенутую цифру с помощью перечисления и сложения элементов. Можно ли сделать его более коротким или сделать циклом. Хочу расширить кругозор.я понимаю что можно сделать циклом, но интересно как чтобы понять. Я пытался циклом, но понимаю что мой цикл ничего правильного не выведет.

```
n=1234
n1=n%10*1000
n2=n%100//10*100
n3=n%1000//100*10
n4=n//1000
answer=n1+n2+n3+n4
print("перевернутая цифра n: ", answer)
print(n1,n2,n3,n4)
```

Comment: Понял, сейчас ознакомлюсь, и в следующий раз буду иметь ввиду.

Comment: конечно можно сделать более коротким, не зависящим от исходного числа и хоть с циклом, хоть без. Кстати, это число, а не цифра.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Например ``print(int(str(x)[::-1]))``. Вместо x можете подставлять любое число. Это если нужно получить именно число, а если просто вывести, то и ``print(str(x)[::-1])`` хватит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Циклом:

```
m=0
while n:
    m = m*10 + n%10
    n = n // 10
print(m)
```

Comment: Благодарю, не сразу дошло что 1%10 может делиться и 1 выдаст.

Answer (score 0):

Я взял решение из комментария `Эникейщик`а и добавил его в качестве ответа

```
n = 1234
x = str( n )  # превращаем число в строку
answer = x[:: -1 ] # переворачиваем строку задом на перёд
print( "перевернутая цифра n: ", answer )
```

Comment: И зачем вы это сделали? Эникейшик в явном виде написал, что не планирует оформлять свой комментарий ответом? Или много времени уже прошло, несколько месяцев?

Comment: Вы сделали строкой и использовали как массив ?

Comment: @insolor для того, чтобы при просмотре вопросов было видно, что уже есть ответ. А так же для того, чтобы немного развернуть ответ и написать комментарии. Но видите, это не помогло, Азамат не понимает, строка это или массив. Это строка, с использованием механизма "переворота" `[:: -1]`

Comment: @alex благодарю теперь понял

Answer (score 0):

исключительно для *"расширения кругозора"*, рекурсивно:

```
from math import log10

def rev(n):
    return n if n<10 else n%10 * 10**int(log10(n)) + rev(n//10)

rev(1234567890)  # 987654321
```